# Error installing packages using Synaptic in Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Tags: 14.04, synaptic

Each time I install something with synaptic I received the following error when I click in details:

```
(synaptic:16174): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
```

The packages are installed with no problem at all.

I have google it and I know that many people have this error I was wondering if this is already being analysed or if there is a fix for it...

ERROR MESSAGE From Synaptic:

[image: Error message]

Comment: This information was sent today to Ubuntu Bugs Webpage.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1282542

Answer (score 3):

```
                      Direct Response from Ubuntu Bugs - Ubuntu Quality
```

"This
error seems to just be one of those warning messages that doesn't
really break the program at all, so from a bug triage perspective this
is a "Low" (Ubuntu Bug Triage importance), or "Minor" (Debian BTS
importance), bug importance."

Answer (score 3):

There is a full [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1282542) on Launchpad : `GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed`

See post #52 and #60 for resolution details.

The reason was a bug in libvte-2.90 (Terminal Emulator) used in Trusty 14.04. This has been corrected in libvte-2.91. You need to rebuild `Synaptic` against this updated library.

I have the latest version of `synaptic` rebuild for Trusty 14.04 in my Ubuntu `Photo Video Applications` [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~anton+/+archive/ubuntu/photo-video-apps), if you would like to update:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repostory ppa:anton+/photo-video-apps
$ sudo apt-get update
```